# Python Telegram Bot check that user only gave a text message

Tags: python

I am trying to make a python telegram bot. Everything is well, except that I would like to send a message telling the user that the bot only accepts text messages and not others (eg. files, photos, stickers) if they do send such inputs to the bot. How should I go about doing so?

I tried using update.message.text but it seems to only contain the text message given by the user. I tried checking if update.message.text is null or empty string but it did not work too

Comment: you can use `if update.message.text: Respond_to_user; else: warn_them`

Comment: That did not work too